# Truecrypt Causing Other Applications to Crash

Tags: windows-7, windows, troubleshooting, truecrypt, internet-explorer-9

Has anyone experienced Truecrypt causing their applications to crash? Our org is moving to Win7/IE9/.NET 4.5.1...several computers run a webapp that has an IE plugin. Post-upgrade the IE plugin locks up to the point that the entire IE process stack needs to be killed.

I setup a test VM w/ Win7, IE9, and .NET 4.5.1 and experienced no issue. The common denominator seems to be that those PCs are running Truecrypt. Am I barking up the wrong tree or has anyone seen Truecrypt cause issues with other applications?

Comment: Never seen it cause a problem.  Remove TrueCrypt from one of the problematic systems and see if that "fixes" it.

Comment: Well we reimaged the PC and the tech forgot to reinstall Truecrypt. The reimaged PC was working, I'm having Truecrypt reinstalled on it to be sure...

Comment: I assume putting Truecrypt on the VM isn't an option?

Comment: That assumption is correct. I'm told they're not sure what it would do to the SAN and don't want to risk performance issues for everyone else.